The references are not displayed in TexWorks
I installed TexWorks on Ubuntu 20.4 with all necessary packages. But the references in the file are not displayed and the section \bibliography{References} are not displayed, too. There are many warnings like:
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Suzuki2009p1' on page 1 undefined on input line 99.
Can you help me to understand the source of the problem? Thanks!

You might be better off asking this on [tex.se] instead

To be clear an app problem not an Ubuntu issue.

Thanks, I asked a question in https://tex.stackexchange.com/ . But I built the same file in the Windows 2011 and it worked clearly. So I thought maybe the problem in the OS.
